# Forgot the name of a program which allows for quick terminal commands on key press

Tags: command-line

If anyone knows the name, let me know.

What it does:
Press something like CTRL+D and a popup appears which takes command line input.

So if I want to open a program using keyboard input and without directly  using the terminal, I use that.

Answer (score 0):

Found it: dmenu app launcher.

Thanks.